# How to update cart data in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to update the cart data not only item and options, I have `aw_sarp_subscription_type` in cart, that I want to update when customer click the update button. Please help me.

Comment: This is the cart data which I print.
Array
(
    [15088] => Array
        (
            [aw_sarp_subscription_type] => 8
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 60
                )

            [qty] => 5
        )

    [15089] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [15090] => Array
        (
            [aw_sarp_subscription_type] => 6
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 9
                )

            [qty] => 1
        )

)